# Excel interop - Problem with recalculating the specific range

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

Here's the current code I have got

```
private void recalculateRRange(Excel.Range UsedRange)
{
    Excel.Range currentRRange = null, firstRRange = null;
    currentRRange = (Excel.Range)UsedRange.Find("#HERE#", Type.Missing, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    while (currentRRange != null)
    {
        if (firstRRange == null)
        {
            firstRRange = currentRRange;
        }
        else if (currentRRange.get_Address(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, Type.Missing, Type.Missing) == firstRRange.get_Address(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, Type.Missing, Type.Missing))
        {
            break;
        }
        //force current range to recalculate
        currentRRange.Calculate();

        currentRRange = (Excel.Range)UsedRange.FindNext(currentRRange);

    }
}
```

The above method is used to find the cells that marked as `#HERE#` and to force this cell to recalculate so we can get the updated results.

I managed to get this code working a day ago but somehow it's not working now. I guess that code is somewhat buggy anyway as I have been able to capture the exception just one time. I wonder if there's any better way to implement it?

Exception captured:

`Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472
   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.Calculate()`

I don't know whether or not it meant something. My best guess is that probably something prevents `currentRRange` from calling `Calculate()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get means [`VBA_E_IGNORE`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsto/thread/9168f9f2-e5bc-4535-8d7d-4e374ab8ff09/) which in turn means that something/someone is running/interacting on that sheet... this could be a user and/or some complex calculation.

You should set `Visible = false` on the Excel application object and wait a little while  after selecting the `Range` and retry the `Calculate` call when you receive this error...

Another point: you should avoid accessing the Excel application object from multiple threads.

Comment: So you are suggesting I probably shouldn't be using BackgroundWorker in this case? When I was using debugger, I did see this method was running on the Worker Thread, not the VSTO main thread. Could be the cause of the issue?

Comment: yes - this can be one of the reasons leading to this error... please read what the link in my answer says...

Comment: Excel will be in this busy state e.g. while a user is editing a cell. Any COM call that you make to the Excel automation model from another thread can give this error, and you need to handle it and retry. One way to avoid having the error handling spread around is to set up a central call to a macro that will invoke your actual code on the main thread. Then you only have to error-handle and retry in one place, where you call Application.Run("MyMacroRunner"). This discussion from the Excel-DNA group might be helpful: http://groups.google.com/group/exceldna/browse_thread/thread/a72c9b9f49523fc9.